# View or access Google Analytics filter that I created

Tags: google-analytics

I am able to create plenty of filters in GA, but where do I access that filter's data?! I am completely stumped. I have watched and read tutorial after tutorial, and they never tell you how to access the data after you create the filter, which blows my mind.

I find GA's navigation completely useless. I'm stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get it straight; you'd like to view the information that has been filtered out?

I'd advise you to create two seperate views for your property (or two properties), one with filters enabled, and one which includes all raw data.

Then you could add a widget/filter in your raw data view/property which excludes the *opposite* of your other filters.

edit: forgot to mention: filtered out data isn't included in analytics data, ever.

Comment: Thank you so much, if only GA or any of the blogs I was reading had explained it so concisely. I wasn't seeing the connection between profiles and filters. Thanks again :)

Comment: Oh and I was adding a filter to include only subdirectory traffic.

Comment: No problem. Just remember to *always* set up one profile with no filters whatsoever, just in case something goes wrong with one of our filters and you lose potentially valuable data.